# Use-case of non-persistence messages in message queue

Tags: queue, activemq-classic, message-queue

I was reading about Messaging Queues and found that the messages can be of two types : Persistence and Non-Persistence .

Persistence Message are stored in disk/database so that they will survive a broker restart while the Non-Persistence Messages are stored in Memory which do not survive a broker restart.

Persistent messaging is usually slower than non-persistent delivery.

But I am unable to think of a specific use-case of non-persistent messages.

Can anyone give an example when a programmer should use non-persistent messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, when it doesn't matter much if you lose some messages.
For example, railroad signaling... the signals send their state every few seconds. If one or two get lost, there are more coming.
Or stock price display... if the display fails to update for a bit, it's not really a big deal. Not talking about trading activity here - just display in a public area or something.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from specific "business" applications where persistence might not be required, there is another important reason why non-persistent messages might be preferred over persistent ones - *performance*. Sending and consuming non-persistent messages is almost always much, much faster than the same operations with persistent messages. When dealing with persistent messages the broker must interact with a storage device (e.g. local HDD, local SSD, network attached storage, etc.) which will usually be orders of magnitude slower than RAM (i.e. where non-persistent messages live).